# AWS SDK PHP Class 'Aws\DynamoDb\Model\BatchRequest\WriteRequestBatch' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The only AWS DynamoDb class that does not work with my CI is `WriteRequestBatch` although the class has been found when right click on it, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

```
echo Aws\Sdk::VERSION . "\n";
# 3.20.11
echo CI_VERSION . "\n";
# 3.1.2

<?php

// ...

use Aws\DynamoDb\Model\BatchRequest\PutRequest;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Model\BatchRequest\WriteRequestBatch;

class Example_model extends CI_Model {
// ...

function Dynamo($ids)
{

    $client = Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
        'profile' => 'default',
        'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ));
    $putBatch = WriteRequestBatch::factory($client);
    // ...
}

// ...
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What version of the API are you using? There's a `Aws\DynamoDb\WriteRequestBatch` for v3, while the one you're using seems to be for v2.

Comment: sdk ver `3.20.11`

Comment: when I tried `$putBatch = Aws\DynamoDb\WriteRequestBatch::factory($client);` , I got `Call to undefined method Aws\DynamoDb\WriteRequestBatch::factory()`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. You're not using `Aws\DynamoDb\WriteRequestBatch`, you're using `Aws\DynamoDb\Model\BatchRequest\WriteRequestBatch`. Notice the `use` statement.

Comment: sorry, I correct mysql, wrote you above, any suggestion ?

Comment: There is no [WriteRequestBatch::factory()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.WriteRequestBatch.html).

Comment: I need to use this one `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-dynamodb.html#dynamodb-wrb` [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-dynamodb.html#dynamodb-wrb)

Comment: How come? That’s the API reference for v2, but you’re using v3

Comment: @ishegg, thank you, I missed that, you solved my issue :)

Comment: Glad you could solve it!